# Destructuring import failing, all keys undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an `index.js` file that has the following exports:

```
const mainPipe = require('./mainPipe')
const mongooseDriverPipe = require('./mongooseDriverPipe')
const neo4jDriverPipe = require('./neo4jDriverPipe')
const postgreDriverPipe = require('./postgreDriverPipe')
const redisDriverPipe = require('./redisDriverPipe')

exports.mainPipe = mainPipe
exports.mongooseDriverPipe = mongooseDriverPipe
exports.neo4jDriverPipe = neo4jDriverPipe
exports.postgreDriverPipe = postgreDriverPipe
exports.redisDriverPipe = redisDriverPipe
```

I then import:

```
const { mongooseDriverPipe } = require('../../pipes')
console.log(mongooseDriverPipe) // undefined
```

If I:

```
const pipes = require('../../pipes')
console.log(pipes) // Logs an object with the above five keys
console.log(pipes.mongooseDriverPipe) // Logs the expected result
```

This also returns `undefined`:

```
const test = require('../../pipes').mongooseDriverPipe
console.log(test) // undefined
```

All my paths are correct, I can see the exported object with all it's keys when I don't destructure, but when I try to destructure, all destructured keys are always `undefined`.

I don't understand why the keys are destructuring to `undefined`.

Comment: It seem fine, are you have any circular require dependencies in your files? check this [circular require dependencies](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line to the top of your index.js file;

```
module.exports = exports = {};
```

Require returns the module.exports value.

You can look here for more information https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-module-exports-vs-exports-ec7e254d63ac/

You can also define them like this if you prefer

```
module.exports = exports = {
    mainPipe : require('./mainPipe'),
    mongooseDriverPipe : require('./mongooseDriverPipe'),
    neo4jDriverPipe : require('./neo4jDriverPipe'),
    postgreDriverPipe : require('./postgreDriverPipe'),
    redisDriverPipe : require('./redisDriverPipe'),
}
```